# Subgroups of a direct sum.

Tags: finite-groups, abelian-groups

Let G be a finite abelian group and let $G = G_1 + G_2$ where the $G_i$ are cyclic. Add it is a $p$-group if you like. How do I prove that it isn't the case that, for some $H_i$, $G = H_1 \bigoplus H_2 \bigoplus H_3$, were the $H_i$ are cyclic?

Answer (score 1):

In fact, this can happen; consider the groups $$\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}_5\cong \mathbb{Z}_6\times \mathbb{Z}_5.$$

In general, one can show that if $\gcd(m,n)=1$, then $\mathbb{Z}_m\times \mathbb{Z}_n\cong \mathbb{Z}_{mn}$. This is a standard fact to be found in most abstract algebra books and is a great exercise. The proposed isomorphism is $(a,b)\mapsto ab$. Here, $a,\,b$ are multiplied in the natural way as (equivalence classes of) integers.

Comment: Exactly the example I was 4.5 seconds aways from posting. +1

Comment: All right. Not only that but if gcd(m,n) > 1 then the product is not cyclic. But let's suppose that, for some p prime, all of the groups involved are p-groups (primary groups in the notation for abelian groups. What then?